# get time series in even numbers of hours instead of odd numbers of hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am generating one time-series from using below query.

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', dd):: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone as time_ent
FROM generate_series ( '2021-12-02 11:49:26'::timestamp 
                     , '2021-12-09 11:49:26'::timestamp
                     , '120 min'::interval) dd
```

and it will give me output like below.

```
2021-12-02 11:00:00.000
2021-12-02 13:00:00.000
2021-12-02 15:00:00.000
2021-12-02 17:00:00.000
2021-12-02 19:00:00.000
```

but I need output like.

```
2021-12-02 12:00:00.000
2021-12-02 14:00:00.000
2021-12-02 16:00:00.000
2021-12-02 18:00:00.000
2021-12-02 20:00:00.000
```

currently, the time series hours depend upon the timestamp that I pass. in above it gives me hours in odd numbers like 11,13,15...but I want the hours in even numbers in any cases like 12,14,16...it should not depend on the time I passed in query **'2021-12-02 11:49:26'::timestamp, '2021-12-09 11:49:26'::timestamp**

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (The above query won't run on both.)

Comment: i am using Postgresql

Comment: Have you thought about using a function, which extracts the hours and gets the mod of the hour, if it's 1, then it adds 1, if it's 0 then it's good and can just be output.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7870d5eb2edbb18a670d44bf50f5b36f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('hour', dd):: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone as time_ent
FROM generate_series ( timestamp '2021-12-02 11:49:26' + ((DATE_PART('hour', timestamp '2021-12-02 11:49:26')::integer % 2) || ' hours') :: INTERVAL
                     , '2021-12-03 11:49:26'::timestamp
                     , '120 min'::interval) dd
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b220fdb1d30c10ca17e8ce07333f5ce

Comment: if I change time from "2021-12-02 11:49:26" to "2021-12-02 12:49:26" it will again displaying odd hours

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya ?? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=690c07a3ef4c9d16e2e666198980bc4a Maybe you have edited in only one place? Look - the starting datetime is used twice.

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: how can i add interval of 20 minutes in this query "SELECT date_trunc('min', dd):: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone as time_ent
FROM generate_series ( timestamp '2021-12-09 06:34:37' + ((DATE_PART('min', timestamp '2021-12-09 06:34:37')::integer % 2) || ' minutes') :: INTERVAL
                     , '2021-12-10 06:34:37'::timestamp
                     , '20 min'::interval) dd"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution according to Tilen's comment.

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', dd):: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone as time_ent
FROM generate_series (
        CASE
            WHEN MOD(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '2021-12-02 11:49:26'::timestamp)::INT, 2) = 0 THEN
                '2021-12-02 11:49:26'::timestamp
            ELSE
                '2021-12-02 11:49:26'::timestamp + INTERVAL '1 hour'
        END
        , '2021-12-09 11:49:26'::timestamp
        , '120 min'::INTERVAL
    ) dd
```